# A reason to make friend function with default argument a definition

Tags: c++

The following [code snippet](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ms3EHLrAVuqrZawX)

```
class C {
    friend void f(int = 42);
};
```

gives me an error:

```
 friend declaration specifying a default argument must be a definition
```

What is the reason to prevent only declaration here? In which situation it can be an issue if it would be allowed?

Comment: @Slava the old post doesn't answer my question. I know that this is forbidden, but for what reason?

Comment: @slava I'm not sure that really answers the Q.  It quotes the part of the standard that causes the error but doesn't attempt to answer why this is required.

Comment: Friend *"visibility"* is complex. I care that we might have trouble (when definition doesn't have default).

Comment: @OP your looking for a technical reason, not a because the standard says so reason, right?

Comment: @NathanOliver reason "because standard says so" is good enough for me. You are free to vote for reopen though.

Comment: Second dup's answer has a link to a C++ DR with some reasoning.

Comment: I made the second dupe target the only one as it has the reason why the standard has the wording it does.

Comment: Direct link to the DR: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#136

Comment: @NathanOliver yep. I would like to know why, i.e. any possible problem if it would be allowed.